# tkinter getting slow after initiating some custom made ttk.Frame

Tags: python, performance, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create GUI for calculating all travel expenses. It's not finished yet due to a problem where at the certain point tkinter is getting very slow. I have no idea what I did wrong.

I made most of the widgets as a class. Everything is fine until I try to make `TravelReportExpensesFrame(ttk.Labelframe)` with a a few `ExpenseFrame(ttk.Frame)`.

The creation of the class is in class `TravelReportPicker(ttk.Frame)` in method `travel_id_cbo_index_change(self)` [gui.py, line 515]. If you want to see the difference. Run gui.py with and without lines 535, 536, 537, where I actually call the creation of `TravelReportExpensesFrame(ttk.Labelframe)`.

I ran `cProfile` and the difference (with/without) is significant  while the mainloop cumtime call is about the same.

{method 'call' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}

with three lines mentioned above:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall
77780/10976   43.917    0.001   46.279    0.004
```

without 3 lines:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall
1622/1224    0.660    0.000    0.683    0.001
```

I am relatively new to python. This is my first post and I am not native english speaker, so please be gentle with me.

I published my code at github and the link is below.

[Here is the whole project](https://github.com/jalezi/Travel_Reports_GIT)

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to want to download your whole program. Stackoverflow isn't a free debugging service. It's best if you try to create a [mcve] that replicates the problem in as few lines as possible, and include that directly in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I follow Stackoverflow for almost a year and I understand what is meant for. Actually I was thinking about it. Finally I've figured out that it would be difficult. First I'm not sure that I can recreate the problem and second, I guess the code would also be long.